# asp:label does not respect line breaks read in from text file. Line wrap is not as intended

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a txt file that I am trying to display on an aspx page using an asp:label.

I would like the label to respect the structure of the .txt file, but the text is being display in one big wrap although the page source implies it has been loaded correctly.

An alternative is to use a multiline text box, but this makes me "feel" like I'm missing something simple with the label.

How can I get the label to respect the line breaks in the .txt ?

.cs:

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(@"~/ReleaseNotes.txt"));
        lblReleaseNotes.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(@"~/ReleaseNotes.txt"));
        txtReleaseNotes.Text = sr1.ReadToEnd();
```

.apsx:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblReleaseNotes" runat="server" Text="[unable to read ReleaseNotes]" Width="100%" Style="word-wrap: normal; word-break: break-all;" ></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReleaseNotes" runat="server" Text="[unable to read ReleaseNotes]" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="600" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
```

[image: Screen Cap of results]

View Source:

```
<span id="MainContent_lblReleaseNotes" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;word-wrap: normal; word-break: break-all;">SnowKing Release Notes

0.3 - 13/02/2015 - Add Live Google Maps and Run Catalogue

- Generate Release Notes .txt
- Added single column runs catalogue to Fernie page.
- Added page for Val Thorens.
- Added page for Les Meniures.
...(etc)
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outputting the text directly to HTML with your Label.

Change the newline character to `<br />` and you're golden:

```
lblReleaseNotes.Text = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", "<br />");
```